# How to have the Xcode 3.1 compiler warn of assignment operator in an if statement?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, if-statement, assignment-operator

I've tried searching the documentation and the internet as best as I'm able, but I haven't been able to get the Xcode compiler to issue a warning if the assignment operator is used in an if statement.

I'm coming from RealBasic, where I've got an extremely strong habit of typing this sort of comparison:

```
if x = 5 then ...
```

In C, of course, that syntax assigns x the value of 5 then tests the result to see if it's nonzero, and the "correct" operator is:

```
if (x == 5) { ... }
```

I've found several mentions that the compiler should be able to warn if there is an assignment made in an if comparison, but I cannot find how to turn it on in Xcode 3.1/gcc. I found the `-pedantic` option, but that didn't seem to generate the warning.

Since I've spent a fair amount of time twice now tracking down bugs that turned out to be "=" instead of "==", I'd like the help of a warning.

I know that I can do this instead (which will cause a compiler error):

```
if (5 = x) { ... }
```

...but that requires changing ingrained coding habits, too. Not to mention that it looks clumsy and backward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in ennuikiller's answer did lead to what I needed.

Here's a bit more information for anyone who might find this in the future:

- The compiler warning is "Missing braces and parentheses", or -Wparentheses.
- The warning is turned on by choosing Get Info for the current
  target in Xcode.
- As I finally found out, the iPhone Simulator SDK does **not** show
  this compiler option.
- Switching the SDK to iPhone Device will show the GCC 4.2 Warnings
  section, which includes "Missing
  braces and parentheses".
- After turning on that option in the iPhone Device SDK, switching back
  to the Similator shows that a
  "User-Defined" build setting has been
  added: 
  `GCC_WARN_MISSING_PARENTHESES` =
  "YES".
- If an assignment is really desired in an if statement, you can
  double the parentheses to avoid the warning.

(Double-parentheses example:)

```
if ((x = 5)) { ... }
```

The warning works like a charm, though it does dislike Apple's standard:

```
if (self = [super init]) { ... }
```

I'll probably leave those as-is, though if I end up with a huge amount of them in a project, I'll either double the parenthesis or break out the assignment into a separate line.

Thanks!

Comment: That flag didn't work for me. I have this code: `if (newlyCreated = true) { goToLastElement = true; }` and although the flag is enabled, xcode/g++ does not issue a warning. (note: C++ code.)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the -Wall option I think.

```
int main(void) {

    int x = 5;
    if ( x=5) { 
    }
    return 0;
  }

$ g++ -pedantic x.cc 
$ g++ -Wall x.cc 
x.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
x.cc:7: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

This [link](http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/Xcode/xcodebuildsettings.html) describes how to enable options through the Xcode GUI