# C++ Poker: skipping over If statements, and disregarding values

Tags: c++

I have been creating poker in C++, and I noticed that after I have determined (or so I thought) the player's hands, it shows it always as a royal flush (or 9, in terms of hand_ranking). I tested it and it came out that the if statements for determining hands were being skipped over. Why are these statements not registering, and how can it be fixed? P.S. I know this code is kind of long, if you don't feel like looking at it please carry on.

```
    int hand_ranking = 0;
        bool one_pair_bool;
        int one_pair;


        bool two_pair_bool;
        int two1_pair;
        int two2_pair;

        if (min_all == min2_all){
            one_pair = min_all;
            one_pair_bool = true;


            if (mid_card == max2_all){
                two_pair_bool = true;
                two1_pair = min_all;
                two2_pair = mid_card;

            }

            else if (max2_all == max_all){
                two_pair_bool = true;
                two1_pair = min_all;
                two2_pair = max2_all;

            }
            else{
                two_pair_bool = false;
            }
        }
        else if (min2_all == mid_card){
            one_pair = min2_all;
            one_pair_bool = true;

            if (max2_all == max_all){
                two_pair_bool = true;
                two1_pair = min2_all;
                two2_pair = max2_all;
            }

            else {
                two_pair_bool = false;
            }
        }
        else if (mid_card == max2_all){
            one_pair = mid_card;
            one_pair_bool = true;

            if (min_all == min2_all){
                two_pair_bool = true;
                two1_pair = mid_card;
                two2_pair = min_all;
            }
            else{
                two_pair_bool = false;
            }
        }
        else if (max2_all == max_all){
            one_pair = max2_all;
            one_pair_bool = true;

            if (min_all == min2_all){
                two_pair_bool = true;
                two1_pair = max2_all;
                two2_pair = min_all;
            }
            else if (min2_all == mid_card){
                two_pair_bool = true;
                two1_pair = max2_all;
                two2_pair = min2_all;
            }
            else{
                two_pair_bool = false;
            }
        }
        else{
            one_pair_bool = false;
        }



        bool three_of_a_kind;
        int three_of_a_kind_number;

        if (min_all == min2_all && min2_all == mid_card){
            three_of_a_kind = true;
            three_of_a_kind_number = min_all;
        }

        else if (min2_all == mid_card && mid_card == max2_all){
            three_of_a_kind = true;
            three_of_a_kind_number = min2_all;
        }

        else if (mid_card == max2_all && max2_all == max_all){
            three_of_a_kind = true;
            three_of_a_kind_number = mid_card;
        }

        else {
            three_of_a_kind = false;
        }


        bool straight;
        int straight_start;

        if (min_all == min2_all - 1 && min2_all == mid_card - 1 && mid_card == max2_all - 1 && max2_all == max_all - 1){
            straight = true;
            straight_start = min_all;
        }
        else {
            straight = false;
        }

        bool flush;
        char flush_suit;

        if (min_suit == min2_suit == mid_suit == max2_suit == max_suit){
            flush = true;
            flush_suit = min_suit;
        }

        bool full_house;
        int full_house2;
        int full_house3;

        if (min_all == min2_all && min2_all == mid_card){
            if (max2_all == max_all){
                full_house = true;
                full_house2 = max2_all;
                full_house3 = min_all;
            }
        }

        else if (min2_all == mid_card && mid_card == max2_all){

        }

        else if (mid_card == max2_all && max2_all == max_all){
            if (min_all == min2_all){
                full_house = true;
                full_house2 = min_all;
                full_house3 = mid_card;
            }
        }

        else {

        }

        bool four_of_a_kind;
        int four_of_a_kind_number;

        if (min_all == min2_all - 1 && min2_all == mid_card - 1 && mid_card == max2_all - 1){
            four_of_a_kind = true;
            four_of_a_kind_number = min_all;
        }
        else if (min2_all == mid_card - 1 && mid_card == max2_all - 1 && max2_all == max_all - 1){
            four_of_a_kind = true;
            four_of_a_kind_number = min2_all;
        }

        bool straight_flush;
        char straight_flush_suit;
        int straight_flush_start;

        if (min_all == min2_all - 1 && min2_all == mid_card - 1 && mid_card == max2_all - 1 && max2_all == max_all - 1 && min_suit == min2_suit && min2_suit == mid_suit && mid_suit == max2_suit && max2_suit == max_suit){
            straight_flush = true;
            straight_flush_start = min_all;
            straight_flush_suit = min_suit;
        }
        else {
            straight_flush = false;
        }

        bool royal_flush = false;
        char royal_flush_suit;

        if (min_all == 1 && min2_all == 10 && mid_card == 11 && max2_all == 12 && max_all == 13 && min_suit == min2_suit && min2_suit == mid_suit && mid_suit == max2_suit && max2_suit == max_suit){
            royal_flush = true;
            royal_flush_suit = min_suit;
        }
        else{
            royal_flush = false;
        }


        if (royal_flush = true){
            hand_ranking = 9;

        }
        else if (straight_flush == true){
            hand_ranking = 8;
        }
        else if (four_of_a_kind == true){
            hand_ranking = 7;
        }
        else if (full_house == true){
            hand_ranking = 6;
        }
        else if (flush == true){
            hand_ranking = 5;
        }
        else if (straight == true){
            hand_ranking = 4;
        }
        else if (three_of_a_kind == true){
            hand_ranking = 3;
        }
        else if (two_pair_bool == true){
            hand_ranking = 2;
        }
        else if (one_pair == true){
            hand_ranking = 1;
        }
        else{}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines are causing the issue?

Comment: The debugger didn't catch anything wrong, but when I put a cout statement inside of one of the hand determining loops (i.e. - the if statement under "char royal_flush_suit") it was not printing, but it was still saying that I had a royal flush every time.

Comment: so you stepped over `cout` lines with a debugger and it did not print anything?

Comment: no, as I tried to debug it, I put a cout statement into the if statement. It did not print the cout, meaning it did not go through that if statement, but it still said that variable (royal_flush) was true. Although, this can't be right because the only way to make it true is entering that if statement

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're assigning instead of comparing:

```
    if (royal_flush = true){
        hand_ranking = 9;

    }
```

That line sets `royal_flush` to `true` and always evaluates to true, so it will always set the `hand_ranking` to 9.

I assume you want `royal_flush == true` inside the if statement, which compares the two values. `if(true == royal_flush)` is a good way to write this so that the compiler will catch these types of errors. And `if(royal_flush)` would work as well.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I don't know how I was that stupid. As I went through and put double equal signs on all those if statements, I forgot about royal_flush. Thanks for helping me catch that!!

Comment: @RichRichards, enable and pay attention to the compiler warnings.

Comment: Not stupid - everybody makes these mistakes. I've switched over to the `true == royal_flush` syntax to keep me from getting stuck like this.

Comment: `everybody makes these mistakes` The compiler should have warned about that however. One key to not wasting time tracking down this type of a mistake is to learn how to read compiler warnings.

Comment: `The compiler should have warned about that` Depends on the compiler. Some of them don't warn about this by default (see [this question about Xcode 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405669/how-to-have-the-xcode-3-1-compiler-warn-of-assignment-operator-in-an-if-statemen)). But yes, I agree with @n0rd we should all enable and read compiler warnings.